# What is the best alternative to using taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

If I have a content type that is something like a skateboard design and I need to have attributes that relate to it, such as, skater, year, series, brand, etc.  What would be the best way to implement these if I want a view  where I can sort based on each of these attributes.  I tried using taxonomies but it seems that it creates a query that has 12+ left joins.  The query is taking over 8s with only 1024 designs.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using?  If you're using 7, you can use fields ("manage fields" under Structure-> Content Types).  In Drupal 6, you can use CCK.

Comment: I am using fields.  I was using a term reference because I want the admin to be able to select from a list of possible choices (alphabetically sorted) when entering data but it seems that these create really inefficient queries.

Comment: If you add a field then you can specify a select widget for you values. Using terms will give you joins as, especially in D7, terms are fully fledged entities in their own right.